# Not displaying dates but instead moving them to a different column

Tags: mysql, sql

Having an issue with a join code where the code is executing but is giving me a warning that it is truncating my PROD_INTO_DATE but I noticed that it was entered into the PROD_CAT_CD column.

```
INSERT INTO `goac`.`product`
(`PROD_ID`,
`PROD_NM`,
`PROD_SKU_NO`,
`PROD_CAT_CD`,
`PROD_PACKAGE_SIZE_NO`,
`PROD_INTRO_DT`)

select distinct
c.PROD_ID, c.PROD_NM, c.PROD_SKU_NO,c.PROD_INTRO_DT,
s.PROD_PACKAGE_SIZE_NO, s.PROD_CAT_CD
FROM ods_product AS c
join ods_sale_large as s
on s.PROD_NM = c.PROD_NM;

select * from product
```

[Where the data is being inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpB5S.jpg)

The PROD_CAT_CD has data that should be there.

And where the join is coming from it should be fine because it sees the date as date.

[from the ods_product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14rso.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert the columns in the same order as in the `insert` column list:

```
INSERT INTO `goac`.`product` (`PROD_ID`, `PROD_NM`, `PROD_SKU_NO`, `PROD_CAT_CD`, `PROD_PACKAGE_SIZE_NO`, `PROD_INTRO_DT`)
    select distinct c.PROD_ID, c.PROD_NM, c.PROD_SKU_NO, s.PROD_CAT_CD, s.PROD_PACKAGE_SIZE_NO, c.PROD_INTRO_DT
    from ods_product c join
         ods_sale_large s
         on s.PROD_NM = c.PROD_NM;
```

Once I had a colleague that I respected very much.  She initially had the same confusion with `insert` . . . although you list the columns and the `select` also has column names, the matching is by position rather than by name.